# how to convert string containing HTML element into HTML DOM elements form in Django Python

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I'm a generating a string in the backend(Django python) as following:-

```
str = "<div class='column span4 ui-sortable' id='column2'>...</div>"

return render_to_response('dashboard/widget_dashboard.html',{'str':str}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))`
```

Now, When I make a call to `str` in the template by `{{str}}`, i get plain text, not the HTML created elements.

How do I convert str into HTML elements?

PS: Since the string is generated upon the first page load, so I cannot make an AJAX call and then using `$(this).html(str)` inside the success function of the AJAX.

How can I approach this probblem?

Comment: Hnnnng, why aren't you making a template tag out of this instead of generating this whole string in the backend? Seems clunky and error prone.

Comment: I didnt get you. Can you please be a little more discriptive as why its error prone?

Comment: Generating HTML backend is usually a pretty bad idea especially since you have to write it all by and mix it in with your backend code. Now you might have some really fancy framework that belches all this HTML out (and i really hope you) so i might be talking out of my ass but extrapolating this into a template tag and render a `dashboard/widgets/widget_basicline.html` would take care of much of the headaches. And! You don't have to escape HTML in your templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the [autoescape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) to `off`

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ str }}{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
{{str|safe}}
```

`safe` tag marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output.